# Error when building example app for native module

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a react native module that can send data to Wear OS apps, but I keep getting this error when running `yarn start` for my example app:

```bash
C:\Users\turtlepaw\react-native-wear\example\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
import dev.turtlepaw.rnwear.RNWearPackage;
                           ^
  symbol:   class RNWearPackage
  location: package dev.turtlepaw.rnwear
C:\Users\turtlepaw\react-native-wear\example\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
      new RNWearPackage()
          ^
  symbol:   class RNWearPackage
  location: class PackageList
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --info option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

BUILD FAILED in 13s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
C:\Users\turtlepaw\react-native-wear\example\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:15: error: cannot find symbol import dev.turtlepaw.rnwear.RNWearPackage; ^ symbol: class RNWearPackage location: package dev.turtlepaw.rnwear C:\Users\turtlepaw\react-native-wear\example\android\app\build\generated\rncli\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\PackageList.java:61: error: cannot find symbol new RNWearPackage() ^ symbol: class RNWearPackage location: class PackageList 2 errors FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. * Try: > Run with --info option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. BUILD FAILED in 13s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

All of the code is available at https://github.com/beaverfy/react-native-wear/tree/react-turbo-module

I've tried to install my package using [Yarn's file protocol](https://yarnpkg.com/protocol/file) (`yarn add react-native-wear@file:../`), but it still throwed the error.